# ARM GCC compiler "buggy" conversion

Tags: gcc, memory, compiler-construction, unsigned, stm32f0

### Problem

I am working with flash memory optimization of STM32F051. It's revealed, that  conversion between `float`and `int` types consumes a lot of flash.

Digging into this, it turned out that the conversion to `int` takes around 200 bytes of flash memory; while the conversion to `unsigned int` takes around **1500** bytes!

It’s known, that both `int` and `unsigned int` differ only by the interpretation of the ‘sign’ bit, so such behavior – is a great mystery for me.

*Note*: Performing the 2-stage conversion `float`  ->  `int` -> `unsigned int` also consumes only around 200 bytes.

### Questions

Analyzing that, I have such questions:

1)    What is a mechanism of the conversion of `float` to `unsigned int`. Why it takes so many memory space, when in the same time conversion `float`->`int`->`unsigned int` takes so little memory? Maybe it’s connected with IEEE 754 standard?

2)    Are there any problems expected when the conversion `float`->`int`->`unsigned int` is used instead of a direct `float` ->`int`?

3)    Are there any methods to wrap `float` -> `unsigned int` conversion keeping the low memory footprint?

*Note*: The familiar question has been already asked here ([Trying to understand how the casting/conversion is done by compiler,e.g., when cast from float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215750/trying-to-understand-how-the-casting-conversion-is-done-by-compiler-e-g-when-c)), but still there is no clear answer and my question is about the memory usage.

---

### Technical data

- Compiler: **ARM-NONE-EABI-GCC** (gcc version 4.9.3 20141119 (release))
- MCU: **STM32F051**
- MCU's core: **32 bit  ARM CORTEX-M0**

### Code example

1. `float` -> `int` (~200 bytes of flash)

   ```
   int main() {
   volatile float f;
   volatile int i;
   i = f;
   return 0;
   }
   ```
2. `float` -> `unsigned int` (~1500 bytes! of flash)

   ```
   int main() {
   volatile float f;
   volatile unsigned int ui;
   ui = f;
   return 0;
   }
   ```
3. `float` ->`int`-> `unsigned int` (~200 bytes of flash)

   ```
   int main() {
   volatile float f;
   volatile int i;
   volatile unsigned int ui;
   i = f;    
   ui = i;
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental reason for the conversion from `float` to `unsigned int` should be larger than the conversion from `float` to `signed int`, in practice the `float` to `unsigned int` conversion can be made smaller than the `float` to `signed int` conversion.

I did some investigations using the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain (Version 7-2018-q2) and
as far as I can see the size problem is due to a flaw in the gcc runtime library. For some reason this library does not provide an specialized version of the __aeabi_f2uiz function for Arm V6m, instead it falls back on a much larger general version.

Comment: Thank you, it gives me some clue. Note, I've made all flash size measurements with optimization disabled.

Comment: @drkr The use of "optimized" in my answer is not related to the compiler settings you use when compiling your code but to the content of the compiler runtime library. I changed the answer to say "specialized" instead. I think this is more correct and less misleading.

Comment: @drkr even if in this particular case it seems like the answer would be the same, the quality of unoptimized code is not something worth worrying about, you should only care about the quality (size, perf, whatever) of optimized code.