# Fast float to int conversion and floating point precision on ARM (iPhone 3GS/4)

Tags: optimization, floating-point, arm, fpu

I read (http://www.stereopsis.com/FPU.html) mentioned in ([What is the fastest way to convert float to int on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-float-to-int-on-x86)). Does anyone know if the slow simple cast (see snippet below) does apply to ARM architecture, too?

```
inline int Convert(float x)
{
  int i = (int) x;
  return i;
}
```

To apply some tricks mentioned in the FPU article you have to set the precision for floating point operations. How do I do that on ARM?

What is the fastest float to int conversion on ARM architecture?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't name a function like this `Convert` in real code :P

Comment: @Billy: I get your point. Floor would be better :-)

Comment: back in the day (15 or so years ago) there was a performance problem on x86 when doing normal typecasts (int)afloat, this was due to the default float2int in the fpu registers was a floor and not a round. So for code to be fast in that era special assembly was written. Any code taken from that time will expect float to integer conversion to use a floor operation versus a normal round. However you may get a double hit using a floor function and then a cast to int versus just a cast to int(round to nearest).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short version, "no".

That article is ancient and doesn't even apply to modern x86 systems, let alone ARM.  A simple cast to integer is reasonably fast on ARMv7 (iPhone 3GS/4), though there is a modest stall moving data from the VFP/NEON registers to the general purpose registers.  However, given that your `float` data is probably coming from a computation done in VFP/NEON registers, you will have to pay for that move no matter how you do the conversion.

I don't think that this is a profitable path for optimization unless you have traces showing that this is a major bottleneck for your program.  Even then, the fastest conversion is the conversion you don't do; you will almost always be better off finding algorithmic ways to eliminate conversions from your program.

If you do *genuinely* need to optimize conversions, look into the `vcvt.i32.f32` instruction, which converts a vector of two or four floating point numbers to a vector of two or four integers *without* moving the data out of the NEON registers (and therefore, without incurring the stall that I mentioned).  Of course, you will need to do your subsequent integer computations on the NEON unit for this to be a profitable optimization.

Question: What are you *really* trying to do?  Why do you think you need a faster float->int conversion?