# _ftol2_sse, are there faster options?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have code which calls a lot of

```
int myNumber = (int)(floatNumber);
```

which takes up, in total, around 10% of my CPU time (according to profiler). While I could leave it at that, I wonder if there are faster options, so I tried searching around, and stumbled upon

> http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/7804-fast-int-float-conversion-routines/
> http://stereopsis.com/FPU.html

I tried implementing the Real2Int() function given there, but it gives me wrong results, and runs slower. Now I wonder, are there faster implementations to floor double / float values to integers, or is the SSE2 version as fast as it gets? The pages I found date back a bit, so it might just be outdated, and newer STL is faster at this.

The current implementation does:

```
013B1030  call        _ftol2_sse (13B19A0h)

013B19A0  cmp         dword ptr [___sse2_available (13B3378h)],0  
013B19A7  je          _ftol2 (13B19D6h)  
013B19A9  push        ebp  
013B19AA  mov         ebp,esp  
013B19AC  sub         esp,8  
013B19AF  and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
013B19B2  fstp        qword ptr [esp]  
013B19B5  cvttsd2si   eax,mmword ptr [esp]  
013B19BA  leave  
013B19BB  ret
```

Related questions I found:

> [Fast float to int conversion and floating point precision on ARM (iPhone 3GS/4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483670/fast-float-to-int-conversion-and-floating-point-precision-on-arm-iphone-3gs-4)
>
> [What is the fastest way to convert float to int on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-float-to-int-on-x86)

Since both are old, or are ARM based, I wonder if there are current ways to do this. Note that it says the best conversion is one that doesn't happen, but I need to have it, so that will not be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's going to be hard to beat that if you are targeting generic x86 hardware. The runtime doesn't know for sure that the target machine has an SSE unit. If it did, it could do what the x64 compiler does and inline a `cvttss2si` opcode. But since the runtime has to check whether an SSE unit is available, you are left with the current implementation. That's what the implementation of `ftol2_sse` does. And what's more it passes the value in an x87 register and then transfers it to an SSE register if an SSE unit is available.

You could tell the x86 compiler to target machines that have SSE units. Then the compiler would indeed emit a simple `cvttss2si` opcode inline. That's going to be as fast as you can get. But if you run the code on an older machine then it will fail. Perhaps you could supply two versions, one for machines with SSE, and one for those without.

That's not going to gain you all that much. It's just going to avoid all the overhead of `ftol2_sse` that happens before you actually reach the `cvttss2si` opcode that does the work.

To change the compiler settings from the IDE, use Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable Enhanced Instruction Set. On the command line it is /arch:SSE or /arch:SSE2.

Answer (score 1):

For `double` I don't think you will be able to improve the results much but if you have a lot of `float`s to convert that using a packed conversion could help, the following is `nasm` code:

```
global _start

section .data
  align 16
  fv1:  dd 1.1, 2.5, 2.51, 3.6

section .text
  _start:

  cvtps2dq  xmm1, [fv1] ; Convert four 32-bit(single precision) floats to 32-bit(double word) integers and place the result in xmm1
```

There should be intrinsics code that allows you to do the same thing in an easier way but I am not as familiar with using intrinsics libraries. Although you are not using gcc this article [Auto-vectorization with gcc 4.7](http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/) is an eye opener on how hard it can be to get the compiler to generate good vectorized code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need speed and a large base of target machines, you'd better introduce a fast SSE version of all your algorithms, as well as a generic one -- and choose the algorithms to be executed at much higher level.

This would also mean that also the ABI is optimized for SSE; and that you can vectorize the calculation when available and that also the control logic is optimized for the architecture.

btw. even `FLD; FIST` sequence should take no longer than ~7 clock cycles on Pentium.

Comment: You need to change the rounding mode to get correct truncation. Changing the x87 status word is slow, as far as I know.

Comment: @infact's comment is accurate

Comment: Good point. It would then make sense not to change the status word _often_.