# inline assembler direct double to long long conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, x86, inline-assembly

Due to optimization reasons I thought about calling directly (with inline assembler)
to the functions "fldl" and "fist". Sadly I don't get how to run it since i'm not that god in assembler.

i didn't get further than this:

```
double* input;         
long long output;

__asm fldl input;      
__asm fist output;
```

Comment: If you're not fluent enough in assembler to call a function, then probably you should let the compiler do its optimizations. You have to be **very** good and experienced in assembly to outperform a modern optimizing compiler by hand-tuning.

Comment: I really doubt manual conversion of double to long int results in any optimization compared to compiler. This is such simple operation, that it may more probably lead to worse performance -- as compilers generally can "look" outside each instruction. (is the result needed, in which register to store it; would it be better placed in xmm register etc.)

Comment: @H2CO3: I'd say, probably even that god.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, conversions from double to integer are known to be subobtimal when left to the compiler because it can't make any simplifying assumptions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-float-to-int-on-x86 although that might be outdated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8dh4h17.aspx

Comment: It may be true. Still e.g. gcc 4.6.3 allows itself to made some assumptions and simply write `cvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rax` (and yes, haven't got unfortunately x86 system anywhere nearby, just x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__asm fld input` will actually attempt to read your *pointer* value as if it were a floating-point value. If you want to read a floating-point value *pointed by a pointer*, you have to go through a two-step process: read the address into a register and then read the data using the address in the register. On a 32-bit platform it will be something along the lines of

```
__asm {
  mov eax, input
  fld qword ptr [eax]
  fistp output
}
```

I just tried it in VS2005 and it works. (Note that as other people stated in the comments, `fist` does not support storing to 64-bit `long long`, while `fistp` does. But you probably need `fistp` anyway, i.e. a popping store.)

Comment: Unless you're going to keep using the value, you probably want `fistp` instead of `fist`.

Comment: there is the slight problem, that its a x86 architecture so there is no rax register

Comment: Also `fist` converts to 32-bit integer, not to `long long`, unlike `fistp` (opcode DF /7).

Comment: @chill: MSVC++ inline assembler automatically selects the proper opcode depending on the size of the recipient variable. So the choice between `fist` and `fistp` here depends only on whether the OP wants to pop the result from FPU stack

Comment: @chil: However, you are right: it works with `fistp` and doesn't work with `fist` (???) :)

Comment: @AndreyT: x86 instruction encoding is inconsistent -- `fist` only supports 16 and 32 bit operands, `fistp` and `fisttp` support 16, 32, and 64

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably:

```
double input;
long long output;

__asm fld input
__asm fisttp output
```

This does a 'normal' double to long long conversion, truncating towards zero, just like a C cast.  Very old (pre Pentium4) CPUs don't support `fistpp`, however, so on such machines you need to use `fistp` instead, which uses the current rounding mode (usually round to nearest).  So if you want to eg round towards -infinity, you need to save the current rounding mode, set it to what you want, do the `fistp` and restore the rounding mode:

```
double input;
long long output;
unsigned short oldcw, cw;

__asm fld input
__asm fstcw oldcw
cw = (oldcw & ~0xc00) | 0x400; // round towards -infinity
__asm fldcw cw
__asm fistp output
__asm fldcw oldcw
```