# How does casting from integers to floating-point numbers work?

Tags: casting, floating-point, integer, compiler-construction

Assuming 32-bit values (int32_t, float), they are stored in memory as follows:

```
// 255
int:   11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 (big endian)
int:   00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 (little endian)
float: 0 11111111 000000000000000000000
```

By this point it's fairly obvious that the memory itself is arranged differently, depending on the interpreted type.

Further assuming a standard C-style cast, how is this achieved?
I usually work with x86(_64) and ARMHF CPUs, but I'm not familiar with their respective assembly languages or the way the CPUs are organised internally, so please excuse if this would be answered fairly simply by knowing the internals of these CPUs.
Primarily of interest, are how C/++ and C# handle this cast.

- Does the compiler generate instructions which interpret the sign-bit and the exponent portion and just converts them over to a memory structure representing an integer, or is there some magic going on in the background?
- Do x86_64 and ARMHF have built-in instructions to handle this sort of thing?
- Or: does a C-style cast simply copy the memory and it's up to the runtime to interpret whatever value pops out (seems unlikely, but I may be mistaken)?

The suggested posts
[Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)
and
[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)
do help with understanding basic concepts of floating-point math, but do not answer this question.

Comment: Explicit conversions depend first of all on the actual language used, as different languages have different rules for such conversions. Secondly it could also depend on the source and destination types (float to int will be handled differently than int to int. and small int to large int will likely be handled differently from large int to small int).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll edit the question; I primarily use C/++ and C#.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The question also is about floating-point to integer (and possibly vice-versa). Conversion from int to int is (fairly) straightforward, as you said, depending on the language.

Comment: Languages only need to follow their respective rules: any implementation that does is valid. Anyway, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-float-to-int-on-x86 for “how” this might be done in a language like C for an x86/64 target when it encounters `int i = (int)f`. Of course, other targets, such as those without a native float type, might handle floating point entirely via software emulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `int:   11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 (big endian)` is showing us the bytes in memory order (lowest address to highest address), then that is little endian, not big endian: The least significant bits of 255, 11111111, are in the low address, and the most significant bits, 00000000, are in the high address.

`float: 0 11111111 000000000000000000000` is not the encoding of 255 in the format most commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 binary32. The bits would be 0 10000110 11111110000000000000000 (437F0000<sub>16</sub>, or, when stored little-endian, 00 00 7F 43). The exponent code of 134 represents an exponent of 134−127 = 7, and the significand field represents 1.1111111<sub>2</sub> = 1.9921875, so the entire value represented is +1.9921875•2<sup>7</sup> = 255.

A compiler will generate whatever instructions it needs to work with values. Typically, processors with hardware support for floating-point have different instructions, and often different registers, for integer and floating-point values. To work with an `int`, the compiler will generate instructions to load it into a general register and integer-arithmetic instructions to operate on it. To work with a `float`, the compiler will generate instructions to load it into a floating-point instructions and floating-point-arithmetic instructions to operate on it.

If the hardware does not have hardware floating-point support, the compiler generates instructions to interpret and process the bits representing the `float` in ways necessary to produce the correct results. Much of this is done by calling routines from a library of software-floating-point routines. Inside those routines, the instructions break down the parts of a floating-point representation, do computations as necessary, and reassemble the parts to produce floating-point results.

x86_64 has built-in floating-point instructions,.

ARMHF has built-in floating-point instructions; the HF stands for Hardware Floating-point or Hard Float. (I do not have information that that is an official ARM designation; it may be colloquial.)

When you cast an `int` to `float` or vice-versa in C, the compiler uses a built-in instruction to perform the conversion (unless optimization provides another solution), if the hardware has such an instruction. The hardware instruction manipulates the bits of the representation to compute the result. If the hardware does not have an instruction for this, the compiler generates whatever instructions it needs, likely calling a routine from a library as above.

C implementations that support mixed big-endian and little-endian types are rare. However, if supported, the compiler would simply swap bytes as needed. Some hardware may assist with this with instructions that either swap bytes as words are loaded and stored or that swap bytes in registers.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the byte order. I got that mixed up

Answer (score 2):

Eric explained the details. But here's a specific instance from the x86 architecture: The hardware does come with an instruction that performs the conversion on the value for you. For instance, to convert a double-precision float to a signed integer with truncation, x86 has the instruction [CVTTSD2SI](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttsd2si). And similarly for other conversions as well. And the way the hardware does this is essentially find the bit-pattern that has the same value (with exceptions to handle overflow/underflow of course), typically not that different from how you'd do it in SW, except of course much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification